# Is it possible to insert key index into File array

Tags: java, php, android, file-upload, image-uploading

I am trying to insert a key index to FILE array. I just want to know that is this work in FILE array or not ?

```
$files = $_FILES;
print_r($files);
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
                    [name] => 400.png
                    [type] => image/png
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php5Wx0aJ
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 15726
        )
)
```

what i want is like this below:

```
$files = $_FILES;
print_r($files);
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
                    [name] => 400.png
                    [type] => image/png
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php5Wx0aJ
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 15726
                    [myid]=> my value
        )
)
```

Is it possible to push key index into `$_FILE` array with the PHP function?

Comment: Why don't you try yourself & check ?

Comment: i tired but i guess i am lost. is this possible ?

Comment: Show your efforts so that one can help you where you lost. Though your answer is Yes it is possible.

Comment: you missed `c#` and `ios` tags

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it as follows:

```
$files['image']['myid'] = 'my value';
```

IIRC, the 'image' key to the $_FILES array is the name of the  control in your HTML, if you were just looking for a way to identify which of multiple files is which.

Comment: how about this in android?